# Countable union covers a second countable, compact Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, compactness, second-countable

I think that the following claim is wrong, but I could not come up with a counter example:

Let $X$ be a compact, Hausdorff, second countable space.

Assume that we have the following process: Let $U_1\subseteq X$ be a given open dense subset. Let $U_2\subseteq X\backslash U_1$ be a given relatively open, dense subset. Let $U_3\subseteq X\backslash (U_1\cup U_2)$ be a given relatively open, dense subset. Coninue with this process.

Does it follow that $X=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} U_i$?

Comment: What is your purpose?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma This would be hard to explain. But in general, it is a proof related to almost Hausdorff spaces, so such a sequence can be found and now I want to show that it covers the original space and I can move to finite cover by compactness.

Comment: Maybe post the actual question and your proof idea too

Comment: You could choose $U_1$ to have Lebesgue measure $< 1$, then choose $U_2$ to have Lebesgue measure $< \frac{1}{2}$, $U_3$ to have measure $< \frac{1}{4}$, etc.

Comment: @DanielSchepler can you please explain? on which space? why are they dense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is a scattered space of rank $> ω$.

Another one are sets $(∏_{k < n} \{1\}) × (S^1 \setminus \{1\}) × (∏_{k > n} S^1)$ for $n ∈ ω$ in $(S^1)^ω$.

Answer (score 2):

No. A counter-example:  Let $X$ be the ordinal $\omega^{\omega}+1$ with the $\epsilon$-order topology. Then $X$ is  compact Hausdorff.   And $X$ is homeomorphic to a  sub-space of $\Bbb R.$ So $X$ is  second-countable. Let $U_1=\{0\}\cup \{e+1:e\in X\}$ and $U_{n+1}=\{\omega^n x: 0\in x\in \omega^{\omega}\}.$ The ordinal $\omega^{\omega}$ is a member of $X$ which does not belong to $U_n$ for any $n\in \Bbb N.$

Remarks. $U_1$ is the set of isolated points of $X$ and $U_{n+1}$ is the set of isolated points of the space $X\setminus (\cup_{j=1}^nU_j).$